# Get count of what changed per day from a datasheet view

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, list-view, custom-list, calculated-column

Is it possible to create a view or column which can calculate the count of rows which have been updated by each member of my team every rolling day?

I have tried creating a calculated column but I just cannot seem to get the formula right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your view, From the above ribbon > Click on List Tab > Click on `Modify View`, then do the following:

- In `Filter` section, Set `Modified Column to [Today]`.

[image]

- In `Group By` section, Select `Members Column`.

[image]

- In `Totals` section, Set `Tasks to Count`.

[image]

**[OutPut]**

[image]

Comment: thank you soooo much, I will try this tomorrow and let you know if I encounter any problems :D

Comment: You are welcome, Hope it worked for you, please after test it don't forget to set the answer as answered, it's the true sign beside my answer :)

Comment: i will confirm once tested - also what if the members working day if from 7pm to 7am - can a rule be created so the members "day" match their shift pattern?